# I'm trying to find a way to refresh data after making an edit or delete in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

[image: 1]
If there is some functions like `notifyDataSetChange()` in android studio or some  functions like that

Comment: You did not provide anything... but you can use change `detectorRef` for this

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: @Akxe please can u tell how to use it I'm new in angular and I don't know how to use this detectorRef

Comment: I cannot, you did not provide any info only an image with a table... In an ideal case you should never need the change detector in the first place so...

Comment: it's fine I get what I want to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First way:** I guess you are using `mat-table` and you can call a refresh method as soon as your edit/delete call is succeeded.

```
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

//...

dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<MyDataType>();

//...

refresh() {
  this.myService.doSomething().subscribe((data: MyDataType[]) => {
    this.dataSource.data = data;
  }
}
```

**Second way:** You could use `ChangeDetectorRef` for refreshing the data.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

//...

constructor(private changeDetectorRefs: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

//...

refresh() {
  this.myService.doSomething().subscribe((data: MyDataType[]) => {
   this.dataSource.data = data;
   this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: in my case it work's with the second way thank you so much